# Double align in equation environment

Tags: math-mode, align

I have four lines inside an equation environment, and I'd like to align the first with the third and the second with the fourth. This is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\Rn}{\R^n}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \begin{aligned}
            &\begin{aligned}
                (+)~:&~\ \Rn \times \Rn \longrightarrow \Rn\\
                     &~\ (a_1,\,\dots,\,a_n),\,(b_1,\,\dots,\,b_n) \longmapsto
                    (a_1 + b_1,\,\dots,\,a_n + b_n)
            \end{aligned}\\
            &\begin{aligned}
                (\star)~:&~\ \R \times \Rn \longrightarrow \Rn\\
                         &~\ \lambda,\,(a_1,\,\dots,\,a_n) \longmapsto
                    (\lambda a_1,\,\dots,\,\lambda a_n)
            \end{aligned}
        \end{aligned}
    \]
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image: result]

However, I'd like to align the colons instead of the start of the line. Is that possible? I tried to use a tabular environment, but the result was terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single `align*` (or `aligned` inside `equation*`) will suffice.

Note that *all* of your added spacing commands `~` and `\,` are wrong. Also `\longrightarrow` and `\longmapsto` are, in my opinion, too prominent and add nothing to clarity.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Rn}{\R^n}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
(+)\colon& \Rn \times \Rn \rightarrow \Rn \\
         & \bigl( (a_1,\dots,a_n),(b_1,\dots,b_n) \bigr) \mapsto (a_1 + b_1,\dots,a_n + b_n)
\\
(\star)\colon& \R \times \Rn \rightarrow \Rn \\
             & \bigl( \lambda,(a_1,\dots,a_n) \bigr) \mapsto (\lambda a_1,\dots,\lambda a_n)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible refinement is instead adding some vertical space between the two map definitions:

```
\begin{align*}
(+)\colon& \Rn \times \Rn \rightarrow \Rn \\
         & \bigl( (a_1,\dots,a_n),(b_1,\dots,b_n) \bigr) \mapsto (a_1 + b_1,\dots,a_n + b_n)
\\[1ex]
(\star)\colon& \R \times \Rn \rightarrow \Rn \\
             & \bigl( \lambda,(a_1,\dots,a_n) \bigr) \mapsto (\lambda a_1,\dots,\lambda a_n)
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Semantics and clarity bonus: refine `\rightarrow` to `\to`.

Comment: @WChargin Well, you won't find `\to` in the LaTeX manual.

Comment: What do you mean? Even in plain TeX, `\show\to` gives `\to=\mathchar"3221` for me and gives the right output. What am I missing?

Comment: @WChargin The command `\to`, like `\gets`, is defined, but not documented in the manual. Similarly, `\implies`, `\impliedby` and `\iff` are defined by `amsmath`, but not documented.

Comment: Interesting—is there any reason why they aren't documented? e.g., are they deprecated, or is there any reason why we shouldn't use them?

Comment: (by the way, a quick search shows that `\to` is used three times in the TeXbook, e.g., in Chapter 16: `$f:A\to B$`, so that's got to count for something)

Comment: @WChargin The original LaTeX essentially added to Plain; I don't know why Leslie Lamport didn't include `\to` in the manual. Of course, since many users switched from Plain to LaTeX, the command remained in use. I use it myself and probably you'll find it in some of my answers here, but generally I don't change `\rightarrow` into `\to` if the question has the former.

Comment: After some thought I think I like this answer best. However I still don't understand why it's wrong to add spaces after the commas. I thought that colons, semicolons and commas required one space after them.

Comment: @rubik They already *have* space after them.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that a single `alignat*` suffices in this case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\Rn}{\R^n}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
        &(+)&\colon &\Rn \times \Rn \longrightarrow \Rn\\
        &   &       &(a_1,\dots,a_n),\,(b_1,\dots,b_n) \longmapsto
                     (a_1 + b_1,\dots,a_n + b_n)\\[1ex]
        &(\star)&\colon &\R \times \Rn \longrightarrow \Rn\\
        &       &       &\lambda,(a_1,\dots,a_n) \longmapsto
                         (\lambda a_1,\dots,\lambda a_n)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or a single `align*`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\Rn}{\R^n}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
        (+)\colon &\Rn \times \Rn \longrightarrow \Rn\\
                  &(a_1,\dots,a_n),(b_1,\dots,b_n) \longmapsto
                   (a_1 + b_1,\dots,a_n + b_n)\\[1ex]
        (\star)\colon &\R \times \Rn \longrightarrow \Rn\\
                      &\lambda,(a_1,\dots,a_n) \longmapsto
                        (\lambda a_1,\dots,\lambda a_n)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

depending on your preferences. Note that `\colon` instead of `:` gives the right spacing in these cases.

Comment: although the baselines are actually equidistant, the lack of anything below the baseline in the first and third lines results in the second and third lines looking like they're closer together.  a little extra space between them wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @barbara you're right, I didn't pay attention to this. Added some spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Ithink the horizontal spacing around the colons is too large, and the two groups of equations should be vertically separated. I propose this, simplifying the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\Rn}{\R^n}

\begin{document}

        \begin{align*}
            (+)&:\begin{aligned}[t]
                &\Rn \times \Rn \longrightarrow \Rn\\[-0.5ex]
                     &(a_1,\,\dots,\,a_n),\,(b_1,\,\dots,\,b_n) \longmapsto
                    (a_1 + b_1,\,\dots,\,a_n + b_n)
            \end{aligned}\\[1ex]
            (\star)&:\begin{aligned}[t]
&\R \times \Rn \longrightarrow \Rn\\[-0.5ex]
                         &(\lambda,\,(a_1,\,\dots,\,a_n)) \longmapsto
                    (\lambda a_1,\,\dots,\,\lambda a_n)
            \end{aligned}
        \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]